# Showing serverside validation errors in extjs

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs

For the form fields, we can use `validator` and `validation` functions to validate and show the errors in extjs. How can I show the similar errors for the server side validation? i.e. Validation happens in backend and errors should be displayed if a certain condition is satisfied.

---

I have tried using `markInvalid("message")`, but this only highlights the field and doesn't show the message and also the highlighting goes away when user clicks out of the field.
Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`markInvalid` in fact is the official way to go. By default, the message is shown in the tooltip, you can change that through `msgTarget: 'under'`.

If you want to preserve the error message, then you have to ask yourself, until when. For example, when I change the value in the field, it should no longer show the error message.

To keep the server's message until the value is changed, you have to add to the field a custom validator:

```
validator: function(val) {
    if(this.invalidValue && val==this.invalidValue) return this.invalidMsg;
    return true;
}
```

and then, when the msg comes back from the server, call:

```
field.invalidValue = field.getValue();
field.invalidMsg = msg;
field.validate();
```